# Modify price using jquery in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to modify Product price dynamically when a button is clicked, using jquery.

For example, if there is a button with value "22" , if i click that button, the price should change to "22". For now, i can change the front end text of price label, but i couldn't pass it when adding to cart. Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible. The product would need some sort of backend reference to the price you want, such as an option/variation that includes the target price. So then from there, your JS would just select the relevant option, which would automatically update the product price to whatever it has been set on the backend. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there any way to do mathematical operations in Bigcommerce?

Comment: Can you give an example? If you want to update all pricing according to an equation, you can do so via a CSV import or API import.

Answer (score 0):

The price is pulled from the backend and displayed.
It is possible to read the price. It is also possible to have options.

I can see a fairly easy way to do this by setting up options for a product:
Put the options ( %%Product_AddToCartRight%% is the most commonly used options listing) in a div with the style set to "display:none".
Then have your button "click" the options via javascript or jquery.

Since the options are hidden by the display:none, the button "automagically" changes the price...and could do other things, like make a "Congrats" div appear, or make the price text/box change color. 
This is good, since it not only draws the users eyes to the price change, but triply rewards the user: Better price, price changes (reacts to users click), and the color changes (another reaction to the users click).

Clicking an option does autoupdate the price, including what gets passed to the shopping cart. 
One thing to be aware of is that Google may or may not run any given piece of javascript on your page.
More importantly, googles crawler does NOT click buttons or select options, so any price changes driven by a click or selection will not be indexed by google. Your product will still show, but only at the "base" price.